# Is it possible to make class or function with variable number of arguments without using *args or default values?(like in range function)

Tags: python, class, arguments

I want to create class that has min and max value with default min being set to 0.
I want it to have possibility to set only max value or both max and min with min value first and max second. Basically I want it to receive arguments like range function does.
I don't want to use *args because I want arguments to show while using help() and in my programming environment when I hover cursor over class name.
I know I could make both min and max have default values but I really want to know if it is possible to make it work like range.

Is it possible to replicate how arguments in range work or is it possible only because range is not written in python?

I tried to replicate how variables in range works but documentation doesn't mention anything about these two sets of variables and I am not experienced enough to find what I'm looking for in source code.
Even though I knew python overrides declaration of a class or function with new one if both has the same name I tried writing two init methods but this obviously didn't work. I also tried the same with two classes with the same name and two functions, in both cases I got the same result.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#overload)?

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/

Comment: From description I think overload is what I was looking for. I just need to figure out how exactly it works

Comment: You can have a function that takes the max number of arguments, provide default arguments for parameters after the first, and then internally, you figure out what means what based on how many arguments were passed. I'm pretty sure this is exactly what they're doing in C anyway.

Comment: Why, exactly, are you holding up the `range()` function as some magical example?  What is so special about it?

Comment: I like that when you pass one value it tells you that it goes to stop and it actually goes to stop and when you pass two values it just knows that this time first value is start not stop, you dont have to pass stop first and start second(which would be very ugly in my opinion). Different order of variables depending on how many of them are passed

Comment: Overload takes care of correct variables showing in programming environment but it doesn't take care of correct order of arguments but that I can handle internally. I think it isn't exactly what range is doing but should look almost the same

Comment: It's pretty much *exactly* what `range` is doing internally: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a929d432b48775096d40f5c72bcd9be052b0a2d/Objects/rangeobject.c#L77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the documentation lists two different versions of [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

```
class range(stop)
class range(start, stop[, step])
```

There's no way to implement literally two versions like this in Python, there can only be a single implementation, which will have to figure out its arguments internally:

```
def range(start, stop=None, step=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = start
    ...
```

You can dress this up to appear with two very different signatures using [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#overload):

```
@overload
def range(stop):
    ...

@overload
def range(start, stop, step=None):
    ...

def range(start, stop=None, step=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = start
    ...
```